# How can I display an uploaded .ppt file on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I have a website and i want to upload a .ppt file to web and show it like slideshare.net, slideshare.net can be used like a Microsoft PowerPoint or libre office. Is there a script allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can upload the presentation on slideshare;
2. Then open it in view mode & click the embed button on the player;
3. Copy the generated `iframe` markup and include in your site.

Methinks this is the easiest approach to integrate a slideshow on a webpage.

[Here's more info](http://help.slideshare.com/entries/438663-Can-I-embed-a-presentation-on-my-blog-without-the-related-content-suggestions-showing-up-at-the-end-) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some alternative option. If you are using WordPress for your website then you can take screenshot of each page, then upload it as a picture and then in the media, show all the pictures in a gallery mode then you will be able to show all the slides like "SlideShare".